# Objective-C Array-Style Subscripting with C pointers?

Tags: objective-c, c, clang

I love the new Objective-C subscripting:

```
id anotherObject;
someObject[2] = anotherObject;
```

But is it possible to implement it for non object types though? e.g. `void *`?

```
void *myPointer;
someObject[2] = myPointer;
```

By *possible* I really mean possible, without any notion of elegance attached.

Comment: why dont you try? And by the way [] is used for arrays and dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have your objects implement indexed subscripting you need to implement the following two methods (for numerical indexing):

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
- (void)setObject:(id)obj atIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

Now you can either pass NSValues that wrap your `void*` and use regular NSArrays like so:

```
myArray[i] == [NSValue valueWithPointer:myVoidPtr];
myVoidPtr = [myArray[i] pointerValue];
```

Or implement your own collection with your own version of these methods BUT this will require you to bridge cast in and out of your collection like this:

```
myArray[i] == (__bridge id)myVoidPtr;
myVoidPtr = (__bridge void*)myArray[i];
```

Neither offer a very satisfactory solution. The NSValue wraping approach could be made better with a couple of macros to do the wrapping and unwrapping but you loose the direct indexing.